# How to pre-select DropDownListFor item?

Tags: razor-pages, html.dropdownlistfor

I have this in a razor page:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.UserCulture, // eg: "United Kingdom (+44)"
    Model.Countries.Select(m => new SelectListItem {
        Text = m.Name + " (" + m.CallingCode + ")", // eg: "United Kingdom (+44)"
        Value = m.CallingCode  // eg: "+44"
    }).ToList(),
    Model.UserCulture // eg: "United Kingdom (+44)"
)
```

As far as I can tell, the parameters to `DropDownListFor` are:

1. Specifying the model property to set when the form is posted back
2. Building the list of items to populate the drop down list
3. Providing a default 'item 0' to add to the top of the drop down and pre-select

I would like to avoid #3 (I don't want an item to be added to the top of the drop down) and simply have the drop down pre-select the item specified by `m.UserCulture` (or, rather, `Model.UserCulture`).

In short, my problem appears to be that the only way to pre-select an item (with this tag helper) is if that item is added to the top of the drop down with the third parameter.

Comment: I had the same problem and i honestly don't know if there's a better solution, but to overcome this problem i rendered the Dropdownlist manually with the `<select>` and `<option>` tags and then using if statements to place the `selected` where i need it

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually using a tag helper. You are using the "old" HTML helper approach from classic MVC. The recommended approach in ASP.NET Core is to actually use a [select tag helper](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/select-tag-helper). The `asp-items` attribute takes a `SelectList` or a collection of `SelectListItem`. The `asp-for` attribute takes the item to which the selected value is bound. You set the selected value by giving it a default value:

```
// PageModel properties
[BindProperty] 
public string UserCulture { get; set; } = "United Kingdom (+44)";

public List<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }

// instantiate in e.g.  OnGet
Options = Model.Countries.Select(m => new SelectListItem {
    Text = m.Name + " (" + m.CallingCode + ")", // eg: "United Kingdom (+44)"
    Value = m.CallingCode  // eg: "+44"
}).ToList()

<select asp-for="UserCulture" asp-items="Model.Options"></select>
```